# Why is String concatenation not allowed here in the second case?

Tags: java

The second case gives compilation error,shows 5 is string while 4 is int.This should be the case with the first case also but it gives output.Why????

```
class Test
    {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    System.out.println("The sum is: "+5*4);   //Gives output The sum is: 20

    System.out.println("The sum is: "+5-4);  

    //Gives compilation error shows 5 is string while 4 is int.This should be the case with prevous case also but it gives output.Why????
    }
    }
```

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)

Comment: will work if you put 5-4 inside ().And this is happening because of precedence.

Answer (score 2):

The Java rules for [operator precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) state that `*` binds more tightly than `+`, but `-` does not.

That means that the first expression is the same as `"The sum is: " + (5 * 4)`, which evaluates to `"The sum is:  20"`.  However, the second expression is the same as `("The sum is: " + 5) - 4` which makes no sense - you can't subtract a number from a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
"The sum is: "+5*4
```

contains a `*` which has a higher precendence than `+`. Thus, `5*4` is evaluated first. Then the concatenation implicitly converts the `int` result to a `String`.

---

```
"The sum is: "+5-4
```

In this case, both `+` and `-` have the same precendence. Thus, the whole expression is evaluated from left to right. The concatenation also implicitly converts the `5` into a `String`. The next operation fails because you cannot subtract an `int` from a `String`. In order to enforce the right evaluation, use parentheses.

Note that if we did the subtraction first this would work:

```
5-4+" is the sum"
```